# Upgrading Linux kernel module without reboot

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-device-driver

Is there any way to upgrade linux driver module without rebooting the system ?

Comment: If your module is currently unused, you should be able to `rmmod` and `insmod` it. Then, there is also `KSplice`: https://www.ksplice.com/. Generally, this question better fits on http://superuser.com/ or http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 2):

Yes we can upgrade without rebooting system. There are couple of tutorials available, please refer few below

http://korovamilky.tumblr.com/post/16460518079/running-new-linux-kernel-without-rebooting
https://askubuntu.com/questions/193069/how-can-i-upgrade-my-servers-kernel-without-rebooting
http://www.zdnet.com/kernelcare-new-no-reboot-linux-patching-system-7000029127/

Hope it will be useful